# Rails: Allow unicode characters in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode

I need help with my routes.rb file in Rails 4.

It contains this line:

```
get 'search/:term(/:radius)(/:order)(/:offset)' => 'search#find'
```

So when i type url like:

```
localhost/search/foo
```

it calls *find* method in the *Search* controller with param *term=foo* and everything is OK

However, when i type:

```
localhost/search/baráááščř
```

I receive this error:

> ActionController::BadRequest in SearchController#find
> Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"term"=>"foobar\xC5\xA1\xC4\x8D\xC5\x99"}

How can I avoid this error and allow all characters except slash to be in the *term* param?

Comment: Ok, so what is the correct syntax for my routes.rb to allow any utf8 word and pass it as parameter? Thanks.